# Not able to install any packages from npm

Tags: node.js, npm

So when I type any command related to installation of any package from npm(Node Package Manager), it shows the error mentioned in the image.  [My Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRwlL.png)

Can Anyone help me out with this issue?

I tried to install typescript from npm but it gave me the following error.

```
npm WARN config key `key` and `cert` are no longer used for most registry operations.
npm WARN config Use registry scoped `keyfile` and `certfile` instead.
npm WARN config     Example:
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:keyfile=/path/to/key.pem
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:certfile=/path/to/cert.crt
npm WARN config key `key` and `cert` are no longer used for most registry operations.
npm WARN config Use registry scoped `keyfile` and `certfile` instead.
npm WARN config     Example:
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:keyfile=/path/to/key.pem
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:certfile=/path/to/cert.crt
npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED
npm ERR! error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-18T14_26_40_348Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: what is node version?

Comment: Version is v18.16.0